# Отправка заголовков

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста почему заголовки отправляются даже после вывода на экран.

```
<?php
        echo 'Привет';
        header('Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8');

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю у вас в **php.ini** прописана директива **output-buffering**.
Из http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php

> Чтобы обойти эту проблему, можно буферизовать вывод скрипта. В этом случае все выводимые данные будут буферизоваться на сервере, пока не будет дана явная команда на пересылку данных. Управлять буферизацией можно вручную функциями ob_start() и ob_end_flush(), либо задав директиву **output_buffering** в конфигурационном файле php.ini, или же настроив соответствующим образом конфигурацию сервера

Также http://php.net/manual/ru/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering.

Comment: Спасибо помогло!